# How should I interpret this decision tree (in R)?

Tags: r, tree, classification, decision-tree

I've performed regression analysis and I've got that the relationship between $Y$ and my ${X}_{i}$ is not linear. However, I'm not interested about the kind of relationship, I just wanted to know if there is or not a relationship. After regression I drew a tree, just to explore possible rules of classification or something similar ; but I don't know how should  I interpret the tree? Can you help me, guys?

My code is:

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Y~AGE+ALCOHOL, method="anova", data=data)
plot(fit, uniform=TRUE, main="Classification Tree")
text(fit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)
```

Where my response variable $Y$ is the concentration of a certain substance;
And my tree is:
[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDmPP.jpg)

Comment: "but I don't know how should I interpret the tree?" Be a little bit more concrete...what exactly do you not understand? In the classification tree you can see the splits of the class. tree ... as you also already stated. Did you expect something else?

Comment: You could for example read the very left branch of the tree the following: If ALCOHOL < 4.35 and AGE < 50.5 and AGE < 27.5 THEN Y = 6.088

Comment: Is this your question? or was the question about how you find out about relationships between variables?

Comment: Yes, that's one of my doubts, but, for example, at the first step: "If AGE<50.5 of AGE <56.5..." But, actually the tree is trying to say " If your AGE is greater tha 50.5 but less than 56.5..."?

Comment: And Yes again. I'm not sure if this is the best way to find out relationships between my variables

Comment: Look at my second post, you read one branch till the result. (then it makes sense)

Comment: one standard way of determining the relationship is calculating the correlation.

Comment: My last question is: My Y is taking values much greater than 6. (Between 180 and 1700). So, why the 6?

Comment: probably has to do with your data and model. Maybe there was just data with Y values between 6 and 7 in your dataset you used to fit the model.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll review my data